# Drupal images issue after enabling cache

Tags: image, drupal

As much as 75% of images are not loading on my Drupal 7 website.  The images in the public folder are being overwritten/renamed with number extensions (Original was: myimage.jpg but is replaced with myimage_0.jpg or myimage_1.jpg, etc).  This breaks the image links.  Both the original image and the styled version have this same issue.

When editing the node or the view, all the images are visible.   But after saving, the majority of images are not visible and link to a non-existent renamed image file.

I thought it might be permissions-related.  The images folders are 755.  Maybe cache-based problem? Although the problem is not corrected when flushing all cache. I do not have imagecache but do have all performance cache enabled, then installed Boost to increase site performance due to slow loading time.

Is there a way to prevent Drupal from continually renaming/overwriting the original image files or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

What action are you doing to cause this?  As I understand it Drupal will created the image-0.jpg file if image.jpg already exist.  That's a normal behavior.